# Why can I not add this object to array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hello I have the following code:

```
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();

    ArrayList<Worker> workerList = null;

            //Create Worker
            System.out.println ("You have selected create worker. \n" + "please enter a name for the worker.\n");

            //Create new worker object
            scanner.nextLine();
            String tName = scanner.nextLine();

            Worker newWorker = new Worker (tName, date, 0); 

            workerList.add(newWorker);

            wCurrent = newWorker;
```

and

```
Worker (String s, Date d, int i){
    workerName = s;
    dateEmployed = d;
    jobsCompleted = i;
}
```

However it always crashes at the workerList.add, where is my error?
Netbeans says `"Null Pointer Defference"` I do not know what that means... Please help

---

**EDIT!
Thanks it fixed it!**

Just another quick question

I have also got

```
   public String toString(){
       return "The worker " + workerName + " has completed "+ jobsCompleted + " jobs";
    }
```

But but everytime I am calling the toString method it crashes. This is after I create the object.

Comment: You've forgotten to assign your list to a List instance: `List<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<Worker>();`

Comment: Why don't you help me instead of saying possible duplicate? You're not doing anybody good @NamanGala

Comment: We are here to help only. That's why I gave you good stuff from stack overflow which I think you did not refer before. It will clear many concepts. And you can check out answers given by people from SO below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<Worker> workerList = null;
```

You initialized it to null. Hence the crash. You need to initialize properly

```
 ArrayList<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<Worker>();
```

And even better with interface programming (Instead of ArrayList on left hand side, declare a List)

```
 List<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<Worker>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need to initialize your list. You create a variable `ArrayList<Worker> workerList` and fill it with `null`. Do `List<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<>();` for a correct initialization when declaration or `workerList = new ArrayList<>();` if you want to initialize it later after the declaration, which is often usefull. You can read [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for further information.